# TinyMCE and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am a rails n00b.
I want to use tinyMCE instead of a textarea that got created automatically via scaffolding.
so Im using [tinyMCE hammer](http://tinymcehammer.lanalot.com/tutorials/getting_started/). the scaffolding automatically created this line

```
<%= f.text_area :descripcion %>
```

and I substituted it with

```
<%= tinymce(:descripcion) %>
```

When I load the view it looks just fine but when I try to submit the descripcion field of my model object is null.... help please

Comment: What is the HTML that gets generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the f. if you're in a form_for block:

```
<%= f.tinymce :descripcion %>
```